# Microsoft Project Online / Server - Accessing Summary task information

Tags: ms-project

I am running a report and it would be great to identify the summary task of a task - is this possible?
Reporting via the project API.

E.g. I have the following schedule

| WBS | Task | Resource | Custom Field | Summary | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Project Initiation Document |  |  | Yes | 01/02/2021 | 22/02/2021 |
| 1.1 | Draft | PM | Governance Doc | No | 01/02/2021 | 06/02/2021 |
| 1.2 | Review | Steering group | Governance Doc | No | 06/02/2021 | 11/02/2021 |
| 1.3 | Update | PM | Governance Doc | No | 11/02/2021 | 16/02/2021 |
| 1.4 | Sign-off | Steering group | Governance Doc | No | 16/02/2021 | 21/02/2021 |
| 1.5 | Publish | PM | Governance Doc | No | 21/02/2021 | 22/02/2021 |

And wish to return the following table via the reporting API

| Document | Task | Resource | Start | End |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project Initiation Document | Draft | PM | 01/02/2021 | 06/02/2021 |  |  |
| Project Initiation Document | Review | Steering group | 06/02/2021 | 11/02/2021 |  |  |
| Project Initiation Document | Update | PM | 11/02/2021 | 16/02/2021 |  |  |
| Project Initiation Document | Sign-off | Steering group | 16/02/2021 | 21/02/2021 |  |  |
| Project Initiation Document | Publish | PM | 21/02/2021 | 22/02/2021 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: In recent versions of MSP, each task possesses a text field called "SummaryTaskName" which might suit your needs.  It's easily accessible in the user interface (desktop) and through vba, but I have no idea how to access it through the POL API.

Comment: Hi Tom, i was aware of that text field and searched the data returned by the API but thta field was not present. There is a field called "SummaryTaskName" which is effectively the same thing and what i need. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API includes a field called "SummaryTaskName" which provides the "document" field needed in the second table above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very possible.

So it could be achieved by updating the task platform as the project progresses and the API only shows u these updated wherever the API key / credentials is monitored from...

Comment: Hi Olivia, not sure that i follow your answer. I have updated my question with tables showing what i want to achieve.